# Yii2 выборка по модели в массив

Tags: php, yii2

Есть таблица и модель под нее, несколько записей параметров для вывода в качестве лэйблов.

- `name` отображаемое на сайте имя,
- `val` значение (обычно от 0 до 10-20 ),
- `section`  признак секции к которой принадлежит данный параметр

[image: вот скрин с phpmyadmin]
Пытаюсь выбрать из таблицы значения для `section='access'` как массив и подставить в `DepDrop`.

Делаю так:

```
$options=$options::find(['LIKE', 'section', 'access'])->orderBy('prior')->asArray()->all();
```

Получаю все записи:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => Для всех пользователей [val] => 0 [section] => access [prior] => 0 [name_en] => access_1 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 5 [name] => Командное [val] => 0 [section] => eventtype [prior] => 0 [name_en] => eventtype_1 ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 2 [name] => Для друзей (семья входит в друзья) [val] => 1 [section] => access [prior] => 1 [name_en] => access_2 ) [3] => Array ( [id] => 6 [name] => Семейное [val] => 1 [section] => eventtype [prior] => 1 [name_en] => eventtype_2 ) [4] => Array ( [id] => 3 [name] => Только для семьи [val] => 2 [section] => access [prior] => 2 [name_en] => access_3 ) [5] => Array ( [id] => 7 [name] => Личное [val] => 2 [section] => eventtype [prior] => 2 [name_en] => eventtype_2 ) [6] => Array ( [id] => 4 [name] => Только мне лично [val] => 3 [section] => access [prior] => 3 [name_en] => access_4 ) )
```

Подскажите, что я не так делаю?

Думал что `Like` глючит, написал:

```
find(['section' => 'access'])
```

результат тот же?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исходя из документации запрос составляется следующим образом.

`$customers = Customer::find()->where(['section' => 'access'])->all();`

Т.е. параметры поиска указываются в функции where (так же можете посмотреть решение andWhere для множественной выборки).
В итоге у вас должно получиться что-то вроде

`$options->$options::find()->where(['section' => 'access'])-orderBy('prior')->asArray->all();`

Советую почаще обращаться [сюда](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/ru). Это реально сэкономит кучу времени.

Comment: Виктор Таиров - спасибо, я туда заглядывал сегодня, но не нашел ответа на такой вопрос:
Customer::updateAll(['status' => Customer::STATUS_ACTIVE], ['like', 'email', '@example.com']);
это пример из дока, но мне нужен допустим Like 'инж%', то есть проверка что профессия начиналась с инж, подскажите как это сделать

Comment: @SergeyP иногда вы можете захотеть добавить процентные символы самостоятельно, вы можете предоставить третий операнд `false` чтобы сделать это. Например `['like', 'name', '%tester', false]` сгенерирует name LIKE '%tester'

Comment: @ Blacknife спасибо

Comment: @SergeyP скорее всего не знаете пока как правильно искать по документации. Советую просто прочитать всю документацию в свободное время. Можно даже не зацикливаться и разбираться в примерах кода, просто чтобы понять структуру документации и возможности framework'a. Потом будет проще понимать где искать ту или иную функцию.

Comment: Всем спасибо, особенно @ВикторТаиров за правильный ответ. Да с поиском сложновато у меня)